# AddAll causing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

Why does retrievedObjects.addAll cause java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?  It does not happen every time but occasionally throws ConcurrentModificationException and I can't figure out why.

```
public Set<Obj> retrieve(Vector2 pos, float radius) {
    Set<Obj> retrievedObjects = new HashSet<>();

    String[] grids = getGridsObjIsIn(pos, radius);

    for (String grid : grids) {
        if (objects.containsKey(grid)) {
            retrievedObjects.addAll(objects.get(grid));
        }
    }

    return retrievedObjects;
}
```

Comment: You sure this is your actual code?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's `retrievedObjects.addAll`? Can you post a stack trace? This set is only created in the method, I don't see how it can be concurrently modified at all.

Comment: I guess 'objects' is a member variable and the method is not synchronised, so another thread might be modifying it

Comment: @Alexander Even then I see no way `objects` could be concurrently modified in this method. The only modification operation is to `retrievedObjects` but that was created in this method.

Comment: 'retrievedObjects.addAll()' means iterating over 'objects.get(grid)', which will throw ConcurrentModificationException if modified during the time of the iteration

Comment: "Only happens occasionally" unfortunately doesn't make for a very good [so] question - it's best if you take some time to try to construct a [mcve] which consistently reproduces the error.

Comment: I'll try creating a copy of objects before doing the addAll.  That makes sense I think that modifying it would cause the error.

Comment: @Alexander `ConcurrentModificationException` has **zero**, **nothing**, **zilch** to do with threads.

Comment: It certainly has. If one thread is iterating over a collection while other thread makes changes to it the collection iteration might throw ConcurrentModifucationException

Comment: @Alexander if you're doing that that a non-threadsafe collection then it's UB. If you're doing it with a threadsafe collection then they provide _weakly consistent_ iterators. i.e. if you are using multiple threads on a `HashSet` then an exception is the **best** thing that can happen. Don't confuse the "concurrent" in the exception title with "concurrency" as in threading.